# What's a more efficient alternative than converting a SortedSet to a Vector in Java?

Tags: java, jlist, subset, treeset, sortedset

I'm writing a contact book application in Java. The Contacts are displayed on a JList which uses a Sorted TreeSet list model.

I've added a search field and I've added a key listener to it. With each key entered, the subset function of the list model is used to display a narrowed down set of contacts. I want the JList to display this narrowed down subset.

I'm thinking of converting the SortedSet to a Vector and then using the JList's setListData method to display the results but I know this would be slow and inefficient, and is an even worse idea when you're using a key listener.

So I would like to ask, what's the most efficient way to solve this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would extend [`AbstractListModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html) and use the Set/subSet directly as the source of the data displayed by the JList. Each time you replace the current subset by another one in the model, call `fireContentsChanged` to make the view (the JList) aware of the change.

This way, there's no need to convert the Set to a Vector.

Comment: That sounds pretty smart! could you please give some example code?

Comment: Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data. It explains the concept of an AbstractTableModel. The same concept is used for lists, except there is just one dimension instead of two.

Comment: See also these [Examples that Use Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#eg).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need concurrency don't use Vector use ArrayList it's not synchronized thus faster.

Comment: How does this answer the question? `JList` cannot work with `ArrayList` directly.

Comment: @Petar Minchev It doesn't answer the whole question it was just a friendly advice for efficiency. Quote "I'm thinking of converting the SortedSet to a Vector" I read this and provided a tip that is good to know in the Java world.

Comment: I see, but it is better suited as a comment:)

Comment: @Petar Minchev  With that I can agree.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind your data (in whatever collection) to your list via its ListModel.

See section titled Lists with Dynamic Contents in [Advanced JList Programming Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/tech_topics/jlist_1/jlist.html).